# Insert Firebird Database C#

Tags: c#, firebird

```
FbCommand fbCmm = 
      new FbCommand("INSERT INTO PRODUTO
                   (CODIGO,EAN,DESCRICAO,VAL_PRODUTO,VAL_CUSTO,CAT_PRECO)" 
                   + "Values (@txt_codigo.Text, @txt_ean, @txt_descricao,
                   @txt_valPro, @txt_valCus, @txt_catPre)", ConexaoFirebird.Conexao);
```

[image: enter image description here]]

What's wrong with that sentence? 
I did a open connection in other class - `ConexaoFirebird.Conexao();`

Comment: Where are the variables assigned values?  e.g. `@txt_ean`?  Also, what is the text property of the codigo variable (`@txt_codigo.Text`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing a parameterized query without providing values for those parameters. See [the documentation](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq348/):

```
FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("insert into t1(id, text) values (@id, @text);");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", 123);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", "my string");

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here they bind the values `123` and `"my string"` to the parameters named `id` and `text` respectively.

Also note that parameter names are generally rescticted to alphanumeric, so `txt_codigo.Text` isn't likely going to work.

Comment: Right, but how I can insert to database the values of textbox ? There other method?

Comment: Right,I did that  :        FbCommand fbCmm = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO PRODUTO(CODIGO,EAN,DESCRICAO,VAL_PRODUTO,VAL_CUSTO,CAT_PRECO)" + "Values ('" + txt_codigo.Text + "', '" + txt_ean.Text + "',  '" + txt_descricao.Text + "', '" + txt_valPro.Text + "', '" + txt_valCus.Text + "', '" + txt_catPre.Text + "')", ConexaoFirebird.Conexao);
 Its works'. Thank you

Comment: No, no, no, don't build SQL queries through string concatenation. Your application now has an SQL injection vulnerability. You use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigo", txt>codigo.Textx);` and so on, while making sure the parameter `@codigo` is also present at the right position in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use quote for decimal, string field types, your statement is correct but not clear, you can create clear sql text with sql command builder or you can use Command object of your connection.